# Memory allocation of returned object in c++

Tags: c++, object, memory-management, memory-leaks, dangling-pointer

What happens to the object returned from the last line of following code

```
class weight
{
   int kilogram;
   int gram;
public:
   void getdata ();
   void putdata ();
   void sum_weight (weight,weight) ;
   weight sum_weight (weight) ;
};
weight weight :: sum_weight(weight w2)
{
   weight temp;
   temp.gram = gram + w2.gram;
   temp.kilogram=temp.gram/1000;
   temp.gram=temp.gram%1000;
   temp.kilogram+=kilogram+w2.kilogram;
   return(temp);
}
int main(){
//.....//
   w3=w2.sum_weight(w1);
   w2.sum_weight(w1);
//.....//
}
```

Does it remains in the memory till completion or it gets deleted.

Comment: you return a value which is a copy of `temp`. However, to be really sure what is going on we would need to know the definition of `weight`. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @abhayCpp It will be deleted at the end of each statement w3=w2.sum_weight(w1);
w2.sum_weight(w1);

Comment: When returning `temp` you are returning a copy. The original is destroyed, but the copy lives on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to look at what actually happens:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class A {
    public:
        A() { printf("default constructing at %016zx\n", (size_t)this); }
        A(const A& a) { printf("copy constructing from %016zx at %016zx\n", (size_t)&a, (size_t)this); }
        void operator=(const A& a) { printf("assigning from %016zx to %016zx\n", (size_t)&a, (size_t)this); }
        ~A() { printf("destructing at %016zx\n", (size_t)this); }
        static A makeA() {
            A temp;
            return temp;
        }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    printf("calling makeA()\n");
    a = A::makeA();
    printf("returned from makeA()\n");
}
```

This code produces the following output on my machine (no compiler optimizations!):

```
default constructing at 00007ffe39415d0e
calling makeA()
default constructing at 00007ffe39415d0f
assigning from 00007ffe39415d0f to 00007ffe39415d0e
destructing at 00007ffe39415d0f
returned from makeA()
destructing at 00007ffe39415d0e
```

So, you see, during the call the variable in `makeA()` is created, the value of the variable in `makeA()` is assigned to the variable in `main()`, and the variable in `makeA()` is destroyed. The variable in `main()` is created before the call and remains valid until `main()` returns to its caller.

Answer (score 0):

`sum_weight(w1);` will return a object but you are not assigning it means object never used. In the first case `w3=w2.sum_weight(w1);` it will call the assignment operator as well as a copy constructor and default constructor ( i.e. `temp`)
 . In the second case two instances of `weight` (first one `(weight w2)` and second one weight temp;)  will be created. Hance just before exiting from the main method O/S will call the destructors of both the object. W3 and the temporary object created from the statement `w2.sum_weight(w1);` ( i.e. `temp`)